# Returning a private class that is inside a class

Tags: c++, linked-list, return

```
class LinkedList_Movies
{
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Movie* data;
        Node* next;                
    }; 
    Node* head;

public:
    LinkedList_Movies() { head = NULL; }
    ~LinkedList_Movies();
    Movie* searchById(const string& id);
    void Add(const string& id, const string& name);
    void Print();
    Node* FindPlace(); // <<<<<<<< this func

};
```

Above is my Linked List in `.h` file. 
I want to return a pointer to Node. But in the `.cpp` file, it won't let me do the following:

```
Node* LinkedList_Movies::FindPlace()
{

}
```

and it's telling me: `Node is undefined`.

I know `Node` is private. So, how can I return it?

Comment: `Node` isn't a top-level class like you're treating it to be.

Comment: As long the class declaration is private, you can't do that for public access.

Comment: Linked list are not normally done like this. Also, what is the design reason to make a class private if you intent to have is accessable to the world.

Comment: @andre "Linked list are not normally done like this",
How Linked list are normally done?

Comment: @tsvi A linked list is not *normally done* at all! You'd use `std::list<Movie>` instead of rolling your own.

Comment: These are done "not private" way - if you want it to be private you may as well return "void *", the end result will be the same.

Comment: @tsvi A node is normally a no a private class. This is the first case I've seen attempting to make the Node a private class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to qualify `Node`, as you are currently defining the function *outside* of the class:

```
LinkedList_Movies::Node* LinkedList_Movies::FindPlace()
{

}
```

Note that the caller of this function will not be able to then store the pointer very easily:

```
LinkedList_Movies movies;
LinkedList_Movies::Node* node = movies.FindPlace();
```

This will give a compiler error because `LinkedList_Movies::Node` is `private`. However, this might be exactly as you want.

It *is* possible for them to do it using `auto` though:

```
LinkedList_Movies movies;
auto node = movies.FindPlace();
```

Or, equivalently, when passing to a deduced template argument:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t);

foo(movies.FindPlace());
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all the type name is LinkedList_Movies::Node, no just "Node".

Second of all this probably won't work as the class is private. Even if it works it will be useless to other functions, as these will know NOTHING about what this object is and how to use it. This function you're trying to do can be private, as the Node type is usefull only to your LinkedList_Movies class.

Comment: "Second of all" is that this probably won't work as the class is private (; Even if it works it will be useless to other functions, as these will know NOTHING about what this object is and how to use it. This function you're trying to do can be private, as the Node type is useful only to your LinkedList_Movies class.

Comment: be my guest (; the only problem is that everything is already said, 4 times (;

Answer (score 2):

As you said your self: Node is a private subclass of the `LinkedList_Movies` class. You have to resolve its scope when calling it outside of the class definition itself:

```
LinkedList_Moves::Node* LinkedList_Movies::FindPlace();
```

Otherwise the compiler will try to look for a class `Node` in the global scope that, in this case, doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2):

In a declaration like

```
Node* LinkedList_Movies::FindPlace()
```

the compiler doesn't know it is in the `LinkedList_Movies` class until it sees the qualified function name. Thus, when it is looking at `Node`, it doesn't know to look in `LinkedList_Movies`. You need to qualify the return type:

```
LinkedList_Movies::Node* LinkedList_Movies::FindPlace()
```

Note that parameters don't need to be qualified because they come after the function name, so e.g. this works:

```
void LinkedList_Movies::DoStuff(Node *foo)
```

assuming a suitable prototype is declared in the class definition.

In C++11, you have the option of using a postfix return type, which is a cleaner way to solve the problem:

```
auto LinkedList_Movies::FindPlace() -> Node* {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full name for the Node class, which is LinkedList_Movies::Node. However, what's the point of returning a pointer to a private type in a public method? Only private methods will be able to use it anyway.